# Checking for table columns before adding them in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to script out a table modification at work.  Rather than do a simple "if exists then drop and create", they want it to check for the new columns I'm adding, and only then alter the table with them if they don't exist.

Could someone help me with the script?  Assume a simple table that looks like this currently:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (

[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [varchar] (20) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [varchar] (20) NOT NULL

)
```

.. I'd like to add an `Address` field, varchar(50) let's say, but only if it doesn't already exist in the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[myTable ]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
 DROP TABLE [dbo].[myTable ]
END

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE myTable (

[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [varchar] (20) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [varchar] (20) NOT NULL,
[Address] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL
)
```

OR

```
if not exists(select * from sys.columns 
            where Name = N'Address' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'myTable'))    
begin
    alter table myTable
    add Address varchar(50) NOT NULL
end
GO
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to DROP the table. Just add the column IF it doesn't exist

Answer (score 4):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Address')
BEGIN

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[myTable] ADD 
        [Address] varchar(50) NOT NULL 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF 'col_name' 
NOT IN 
   SELECT Name
   FROM table_name.columns 
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD 'col_name' VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL
```

something like this?

EDIT: my friend believes this is much better

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT Name
    FROM table_name.columns
    Where Name='target_column_name')
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD 'target_column_name' VARCHAR(65) NOTNULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Here using it you can make check for multiple columns and get you table altered...

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns
WHERE Name = N'Address' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'<TableName>'))
BEGIN
SET   
    @query = 'ALTER TABLE <TableName> ADD Address varchar(50) GO'
END 

--You can give multiple If conditions, example:
--IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns
--WHERE Name = N'<SomeOtherColumn>' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'<TableName>'))
--BEGIN
--SET   
    --@query = @query + 'ALTER TABLE <TableName> ADD <SomeOtherColumn> varchar(50) GO'
--END 

EXEC sp_Executesql @query
```